# Android Studio Emulator: Intel Atom x86 vs ARM

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

What are the differences between Intel Atom x86 vs ARM emulator? 
And what are the pros and cons between the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Intel-based devices can run the full range of Android apps, even ones
>   that were originally written for the ARM architecture. However, if an
>   app contains ARM-specific code, then it must be translated before it
>   can be executed.
>
> This takes time and energy to do, so battery life and overall
>   performance may suffer. Whether this is a serious problem is up for
>   debate: our reviews indicate that Intel does tend to trail behind ARM
>   in battery life, but the gap isn’t huge, and overall performance is
>   generally very good.
>
> At any rate, Intel is working hard to encourage developers to produce
>   Intel-native versions of their apps, so hopefully translation will
>   become progressively less of an issue.

Source: http://www.alphr.com/features/390064/arm-vs-intel-processors-what-s-the-difference

Comment: The question is about what is different between the *emulators*. This answer is about differences between the various *device architectures*. The pros and cons of the different *devices* (being emulated) have nothing to do with pros and cons of selecting one of the *emulators*.

Answer (score 4):

It says, "Running an x86 base Android Virtual Device is 10x faster"- while trying to run an arm virtual device. So I guess, x86 is faster.

Comment: You're pretty much correct. A good explanation can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30651276/443136

Comment: @ValerioSantinelli - the answer you link is not relevant, because it confuses the speed-benefit of running a 64-bit image on a 64-bit target device [e.g. when running on an actual atom-64 phone or table] vs. whether that choice matters when *emulating* (it doesn't).

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve actually the choice matters because the x86 based emulator images run faster than the arm based ones on Intel PCs. It’s also true that switching to a qemu based emulator made a big difference in performances of the emulator.