# Should I choose x86_64 for testing rather than the "recommended" x86 for virtual device system image?

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I'm totally new to Android programming. I have Android Studio 3.0.1 running on Kubuntu Xenial 64-bit on a desktop with a Haswell processor.

I am configuring virtual devices. I am thinking of doing that corresponding to the physical Android devices I own. However, I notice that x86 images are placed in the "Recommended" pane:

[image]

compared to the x86_64 images of identical API version and target:

[image]

#4 of https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html#createavd seems to indicate that x86 images are recommended because they "run the fastest in the emulator."

A few of my old devices are x86 but the newer ones are x86_64. Should I choose x86_64 accordingly though it is not in the "Recommended" pane?

Does this make a difference when I am going to distribute APKs on Google Play Store in the future?

Comment: They are just AVD images for the slow Android emulator if you debug using the emulator.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

related to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30651276/4345934) By default, all 32-bit applications run without a glitch on 64-bit processors, but might run slower than applications tuned to run on 64-bit processors.

and according with this [article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/how-to-develop-and-evaluate-64-bit-android-apps-on-intel-x86-platforms)

> With Google’s recent release of its x86 64-bit Android 5.0 emulator
>   image, developers can create 64-bit apps for Intel Atom
>   processor-based devices.

**Android 32-bit vs 64-bit**

> Many 64-bit platforms today, including Solaris, AIX*, HP-UX*, Linux*,
>   OS X*, BSD, and IBM z/OS*, use an LP64 model. Since Android is based
>   on the Linux kernel, Android 64-bit platforms also use the LP64 model.
>
> Intel 64-bit CPUs have a 32-bit compatibility mode. While 32-bit
>   applications will run on 64-bit processors, **compiling with a 64-bit
>   optimizing compiler allows them to take advantage of the architectural
>   benefits of a 64-bit environment**.

Android with 64-bit technologies for Intel Atom processor-based platforms can help developers to **optimize their applications** now. Building Android applications for 64-bit is just as easy as building traditional 32-bit Android applications. You can now use the official Android 64-bit emulator to run and debug 64-bit apps.

Maybe this articles can help you to understand the difference between this system images.

**Update**

Google now encourage to use x86 emulator like you can see in this image

[image]

The difference is that when using x86 images, it now uses fast, hardware-accelerated virtualization under the right conditions ([HAXM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager)) so it doesn't feel like there's a fat middle layer anymore.

Comment: Thanks for this reply. As I'm on Linux I have KVM i.o. your HAXM. Should I understand that these provide acceleration only for 32-bit and not 64-bit?

Comment: You're welcome ! yes, It's dedicated usually to accelerate traditional 32-bit Android applications

Comment: It is my understanding that the recommendation for "x86 based" is in contrast with the full non-Intel based emulator, not that it is 10x faster than using 64 bit.

Comment: How can I identify a 64-bit Android phone *before* purchase?   I know how to determine after purchase.  I need a 64-bit Android testing device.  I can purchase a 64-bit phone but it may be running a 32-bit Android OS.

Comment: so the tl;dr is we should use x86 instead x86_64 right?

Comment: @buncis No. It is unclear based on information shared here so far which of x86 and x86_64 runs faster on a x86_64 development machine.

Comment: @buncis apparently someone tested x86 vs x86_64 and found basic x86 10% faster https://stackoverflow.com/a/65615506/2301224